# Prevent direct access to .htaccess file

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess

i need to prevent access to `.htaccess` file. my file is:

```
# secure htaccess file
<Files .htaccess>
 order allow,deny
 deny from all
</Files>

# disable directory browsing
Options All -Indexes
```

when i check URL :

`http://localhost/cms/htaccess`

I see `.htaccess` file data

How do i can `prevent/deny` access to `.htaccess` file?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're blocking `.htaccess` but accessing `http://localhost/cms/htaccess`

Try accessing `http://localhost/cms/.htaccess`

If you want to block both try this `FilesMatch` directive with regex:

```
<FilesMatch "\.?htaccess$">
 order allow,deny
 deny from all
</FilesMatch>
```

Comment: Yes, i dont access too `http://localhost/cms/.htaccess` But your code not work and i see htaccess file in `http://localhost/cms/htaccess`.

Comment: I have tested it, it is working. In which .htaccess did you place it?

Comment: Oh! this worked. my problem with `.htaccess` and `htaccess` files without `dot`!

Comment: Yes that's what I wrote in my answer about DOT :) Glad to know it worked.

Answer (score 1):

You can secure access Within an htaccess file itself,
the scope of the  directive only applies to that directory,
See the below code.

> ## To secure the htaccess file.

```
<Files "log.txt">
Order Allow,Deny
Deny from all
</Files>
```

In your htaccess file in your local. Also  you can use mod_rewrite to sort of handle both cases deny & access to htaccess file as well as log.txt:

```
RewriteRule /?\.htaccess$ - [F,L]

RewriteRule ^/?inscription/log\.txt$ - [F,L]
```